# std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr as parameters for virtual functions

Tags: c++, interface, heap-memory, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I'm designing a C++ class interface based on `virtual` methods to be able to provide extensibility points.

Lots of these public methods require `heap` allocated object as parameters.

Since I'm making use of modern C++ patterns I'm planning to use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` for that but I have doubts on both of them.

Using  std::unique_ptr it looks like something like this:

```
class IFoo {
  virtual void doSomethingWithUser(std::unique_ptr<User> user) = 0;
}
```

Forcing the caller to provide `std::unique_ptr` has downsides:

- the caller cannot do any operation on the provided user since it has to be moved
- in case any of `doSomethingWithUser` implementation needs to store the user in some container, it is not constructible from `std::shared_ptr`

Using `std::shared_ptr` for all the public methods could solve the problem but we have to pay for extra memory space plus the atomic increment and decrement of the references count.

Is there any rule of thumb I can follow?

Comment: "Lots of these public methods require heap allocated object as parameters." Huh? What does that mean?

Comment: @FredLarson as in the example above user is heap allocated, it does not live on the stack. (User is not copiable by design hence the need to heap allocate it)

Comment: I don't see what heap vs. stack allocation has to do with anything. Do you mean you need to pass by pointer (or reference) instead of passing by value?

Comment: @FredLarson exactly

Comment: @steazzalini being non-copiable has nothing to do with requiring heap allocation. Most of my class are stack allocated, but yet moveable only. You may require heap allocation if move is not an option or either you need polymorphism with ownership of the pointed-to value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `doSomethingWithUser` don't need ownership, you shouldn't transfer it to this method.

Indeed, copying a shared pointer or moving a unique pointer effectively transfers the ownership of the resource.

Your functions parameters should reflect your intentions about the assumed ownership of the passed resources.

If you only need to observe the value, and maybe mutating it, you should pass a non-owning handle to your function.

If you need to keep the resource alive and maybe deleting it, then you should pass a owning handle, whether it's a shared it unique ownership.

In your case, the name of the function tells me that you need to "do something with the user", without containing it passed the caller's lifetime. So you should pass a non owning handle. That handle can be a `User*` or `User&`, and even a `std::reference_wrapper<User>` or a `boost::optional<User&>`, depending on your needs.

Your interface should indeed express what an object should be able to do, and indeed enforce what parameters should each function take, but your interface should also express what ownership it has over it's parameters.

I usually prefer references since they ensure it cannot be null and work well with object in automatic storage. Some may argue that they prefer raw  pointers as a non-null non-owning handle, but I strongly disagree with that, because they force the `&object` syntax and allows null.

There is nothing wrong with non-owning raw pointers. However, raw owning pointers should not be used in modern C++.

Comment: You might also mention weak_ptr, since this is a semantic indication that the function uses but does not maintain ownership of the data.

Comment: > I usually prefer references since they ensure it cannot be null and work well with object in automatic storage, but it's mostly a matter of taste. Uh, not really. There is some kind of bad, misguided argument to be made (half kidding) in the rare cases where you are mutating the object. But passing something that can't be null by pointer to const instead of const ref is just horrible and not a matter of taste at all.

Comment: @wphicks `std::weak_ptr` is still shared ownership, but yet a non-owning handle.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Reference in second paragraph [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) in case anyone had the same misunderstanding I did.

Comment: I totally agree with you @GuillaumeRacicot but the problem remains open for 3rd party implementations which I do not control. I cannot make assumptions about or set limits to the possible implementations.
If some implementation decides to, for example, cache the passed users and I choose to use references, the thing is not gonna work.

Comment: @NirFriedman I updated that paragraph. Tell me if that explanation is better

Comment: @steazzalini I added a paragraph about this. Tell me if anything else is needed.